# creating the UIview and add to the cell of the table in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating the table in which i have the one cell which have the uiview .For this i create class his name is (TColourSelectTableViewController)which have all colour value and.I want to  add this class to the cell of other table view .
IS that possible than give answer
Thank you

Comment: Tell me what u want to do exactly?

Comment: Actually i want to add the UIView to the cell of the table.And this UIView have function of class TColourSelectTableController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a custom `UITableViewCell` and use it in your `UITableView`.

I would recommend this post [UITableViewCell custom](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/)

Answer (score 0):

I would never add a instance of `tableviewcontroller` to a `uitableviewcell`. However in terms of just programming in `Objective-C` it is very much possible. Create a custom class which derives from `uitableview` cell say `TColorSelectTableViewCell` and in the `@interface` add the instance for the tableviewcontroller.

Where ever you plan to use the cell typecast it to the above created class.

Answer (score 0):

If want to use data of class TColourSelectTableController then u simply make it as app delegate file declare here all color values. When u wan to use them in any class of your project then use this code

```
 TestAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TestAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.score=0;
```

Comment: NO i want the TColourSelectTableController UIView must add to the cell

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add a view as:

[cell.contentView addSubview:yourViewControllerObj.view];

Write this in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add any view as:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:yourViewControllerObj.view];
```

Write this in cellForRowAtIndexPath